# mysqli_query retorna false para select feito com REGEXP

Tags: php, regex, mysqli

Estou tendo o seguinte problema: estou tentando capturar uma linha da tabela da minha database usando um regex e, ao digitar o código no terminal do Mysql, ele captura a linha normalmente. Já no meu código php, o mysqli_query() sempre retorna false com esses mesmos comandos. O código segue abaixo:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['pesquisa'])){
    $palavras_pesquisa = explode(' ',$_POST['pesquisa']);
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','secure_login');
    $rows = array();    
    $ids = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($palavras_pesquisa) ; $i++){
    $string = '.*'.$palavras_pesquisa[$i].'*';
    $busca = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome REGEXP '$string'");

//'$busca' sempre retorna false, fazendo com que o restante abaixo não seja executado. 

while(mysqli_fetch_assoc($busca) != false){
        array_push($rows,mysqli_fetch_assoc($busca));
    }
    }

    for($i = 0;$i < count($rows);$i++){
        if(in_array($rows[$i]['id'],$ids)){
            unset($rows[$i]);
        }else{
            array_push($ids,$rows[$i]['id']);
            ?>
                <p><?php echo $rows[$i]['nome']; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $rows[$i]['email']; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $rows[$i]['interesses']; ?></p>
            <?php
        }
    }
}?>
```

Como eu havia dito, `SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome REGEXP '$string'` funciona perfeitamente no terminal mysql. Gostaria saber se estou fazendo algo de errado aqui. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: A sua pesquisa é formada por um grupo de palavras: Exemplo: `nome1` `nome 2` e ai você faz um item por vez? Porque você não usa o `OR` ? Tipo: `.*nome1*|.*nome2*`?

Comment: O código faz parte de uma página php que tem como função buscar um usuário. Seria similar à caixa de texto do facebook, onde você digita o nome de alguém e vários resultados aparecem. Só que aqui eu fiz algo básico, só pra ver funcionando mesmo. Ele pega o que o usuário digitou na caixa de texto e separa todas as palavras digitadas e separadas por um espaço. Em seguida, ele deveria pegar todas as palavras separadas e testá-las, guardando todas as linhas da tabela do bd cuja coluna 'nome' seja igual a $string, ou em que $string seja uma substring do nome. Só que eu não consegui testar ainda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro, a cada vez que usa o `mysqli_fetch_assoc` ele vai retornar o próximo resultado, ou seja no momento que faz isto:

```
while(mysqli_fetch_assoc($busca) != false){
    array_push($rows,mysqli_fetch_assoc($busca));
}
```

Você executa dois `mysqli_fetch_assoc` a cada loop, ou seja **se a sua query** só esta trazendo um resultado por loop do `for($i = 0; $i < count($palavras_pesquisa) ; $i++){` então ele sempre vai fazer o merge de valores `NULL`, outra coisa você comparou com `FALSE` em `mysqli_fetch_assoc($busca) != false`, o que não faz sentido, pois `mysqli_fetch_assoc` retorna ou `array` ou `null` apenas, também use o  `mysqli_error` para detectar o erros.

O mais correto a fazer assim:

```
$busca = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome REGEXP '$string'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

//'$busca' sempre retorna false, fazendo com que o restante abaixo não seja executado.

while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($busca)) {
    array_push($rows, $dados);
}
```

Resumindo, **SEMPRE FAÇA EXATAMENTE COMO ESTÃO NOS EXEMPLOS DA DOCUMENTAÇÃO** (geralmente adoc em inglês esta mais correta na maioria dos casos), mesmo que eles não sejam *ótimos*, ainda sim é melhor do que usar errado, ou usar aleatoriamente sem saber o que esta fazendo, o efeito do `mysqli_fetch_assoc` é semelhante ao `yeld`, pra cada vez que usar `mysqli_fetch_assoc` ele vai trazer a próxima linha.

No entanto fazer um `SELECT` pra cada loop pode ser desperdício, você poderia simplificar fazer isto:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($palavras_pesquisa) ; $i++){
$string = '.*'.$palavras_pesquisa[$i].'*';
$busca = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome REGEXP '$string'");
```

Prefira usar `implode` e fazer apenas uma query, ficando assim:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['pesquisa'])){
    $palavras_pesquisa = explode(' ',$_POST['pesquisa']);
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','secure_login');
    $rows = array();
    $ids = array();

    if (!empty($palavras_pesquisa)) { //Verifica se tem palavras

        foreach ($palavras_pesquisa as &$value) {
            $value = '.*' . $value . '*';
        }

        $consulta = "nome REGEXP '" . implode("' OR nome REGEXP '", $palavras_pesquisa) . "'"; //Cria um OR pra cada palavra

        $busca = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE " . $consulta) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

        while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($busca)) {
            $rows[] = $dados;
        }
    }

    for($i = 0;$i < count($rows); $i++){
    ...
```

Outra coisa, **SEMPRE FAÇA UMA BOA INDENTAÇÃO DO CÓDIGO**, isso ajuda a não se perder.

Todavia é recomendável também não passar dados diretamente na query, isso devido ao sqlinjection, se está usando o mysqli então prefira usar o [**prepared statement**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), ficaria assim:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['pesquisa'])){
    $palavras_pesquisa = explode(' ', $_POST['pesquisa']);

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'secure_login');
    $rows = array();
    $ids = array();

    if (!empty($palavras_pesquisa))//Verifica se tem palavras
    {
        //Gera where
        $consulta = rtrim(str_repeat('`nome` REGEXP ? OR ', count($palavras_pesquisa)), 'OR ');

        //Gera tipos parâmetros
        $paramsTypes = str_repeat('s', count($palavras_pesquisa));

        //Gera referencias
        $params = array();
        $params[] = &$paramsTypes;

        foreach ($palavras_pesquisa as $value) {
            $value = '.*' . $value . '*';
            $params[] = &$value;
        }

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE " . $consulta);

        //Adiciona o stmt como primeiro item no array
        array_unshift($params, $stmt);

        if ($stmt) {
            //Passa array como parâmetros no bind_param
            call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', $params);

            if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                echo 'Erro no stmt:', mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
                exit;
            }

            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

            while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $rows[] = $dados;
            }

            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        } else {
            echo 'Erro no prepare:', mysqli_error($conn);
            exit;
        }
    }

    for($i = 0;$i < count($rows); $i++){
    ...
```

Veja a documentação pra entender as funções que usei no último exemplo:

- [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.call-user-func-array.php)
- [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rtrim.php)
- [str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-repeat.php)

Mysqli:

- [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.prepare.php)
- [mysqli_stmt_execute](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)
- [mysqli_stmt_get_result](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

Entenda as criticas aqui como sugestões pra você melhorar.

Comment: Obrigado pelos conselhos. Vou procurar colocá-los em prática. No entanto, reescrevi o código substituindo  `while(mysqli_fetch_assoc($busca) != false)` por `while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($busca)) ` e mesmo assim não funcionou. Utilizando `mysqli_num_rows()`, eu vi que a query realmente não retorna nenhuma linha da tabela. Vou continuar procurando algum caso similar ao meu.

Comment: eu utilizei o seu código, mas notei tem algo de errado nas linhas `array_unshift($params, $stmt);` e `call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', $params);`. Ao utilizar a primeira, o `$stmt` acaba sendo visto como um parâmetro inválido para o `myslqi_stmt_bind_param()`, o que me dá o seguinte aviso: `Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt_bind_param() in procurar.php on line 47`. Além disso, essa mesma função `myslqi_stmt_bind_param()` não está recebendo os valores a serem substituidos pelos '?' no 'mysqi_prepare()'. Depois comento se consegui corrigir isso.

Comment: Agora deu certo. No entanto, o programa não acha nenhum resultado na db, imprimindo 'Array()'.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41045/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-luca000).